# restart broken tcp connection in windows using winsock 2 lib

Tags: c, windows, sockets, tcp, winsock

am working on a c program that should log data from a norma 5000, but it seams like the normas tcpconnection randomly closes after an arbitary time (0.2-6h) but i need to log longer than that.

when it Closes the Connection i can just restart program and it will continue to log. so i got the idea of just restarting my socket when the tcpconnection breaks. but my restart dosent work every time.. the function i Think you want to look at is shutdownCon, init and main.

my question is: what am i doing wrong?

winsock errors i get when the tcp Connection stops working 10053 (WSAECONNABORTED) or 10054 (WSAECONNRESET).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define WIN 1
#define debug 1

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>

#define HOST "192.168.0.101"
#define PORT 23

#define SOCKET_HANDLE_FMT_PFX ""
#define SOCKET_HANDLE_FMT "u" /* "%u" - 'typedef u_int SOCKET' */
typedef SOCKET socket_handle_t;

typedef struct {
    socket_handle_t h;
} *socket_t;
/****************************************************************************
**/
static void Delay(double seconds)
{
    Sleep((DWORD)(seconds * 1000));
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
void wsa_error(char *func,int error)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"%s() failed, error %d\n",
    func,error == -1 ? WSAGetLastError() : error);

    int c;  /* must be int to hold EOF */ 
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); 
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_setup(void)
{
    #if WIN
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wsaerrno;
    /*
    * Initialize Windows Socket DLL
    */
    if ( (wsaerrno = WSAStartup(
    MAKEWORD(1,1), /* at least version 1.1 */
    &wsaData)) != 0 )
    {
        wsa_error("WSAStartup",wsaerrno);
        return -1;
    }
    #endif /* WIN */
    return 0; /* OK */
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_cleanup(void)
{
    #if WIN
    if ( WSACleanup() == SOCKET_ERROR )
        wsa_error("WSACleanup",-1);
    #endif
    return 0; /* OK */
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
socket_t socket_create(void)
{
    socket_handle_t sh;
    socket_t s;
    sh = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    #if WIN
    if ( sh == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        wsa_error("socket",-1);
        return NULL;
    }
    #endif
    s = calloc(1,sizeof(*s));
    if ( !s )
        return NULL;
    s->h = sh;
    return s; /* OK */
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_connect(socket_t s,struct sockaddr *addr,int addrlen)
{
    int ret = 0; /* OK */
    #if WIN
    if ( connect(s->h,addr,addrlen) == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        wsa_error("connect",-1);
        return -1;
    }
    #endif
    return 0; /* OK */
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_recv(socket_t s,void *buf,int len,int flags)
{
    register int l;
    #if WIN
    l = recv(s->h,buf,len,flags);
    if ( l == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        wsa_error("recv",-1);
        return -1;
    }
    #endif
    return l;
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_send(socket_t s,void *buf,int len,int flags)
{
    register int slen; /* sent length */
    #if WIN
    slen = send(s->h,buf,len,flags);
    if ( slen == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        wsa_error("send",-1);
        return -1;
    }
    #endif
    return slen;
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_puts(socket_t s,char *str)
{
    char buf[1024];
    strcpy(buf,str);
    strcat(buf,"\n");
    if ( socket_send(s,buf,strlen(buf),0) < 0 )
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
int socket_gets(socket_t s,char *str)
{
    char buf[1024];
    char *p;
    if ( socket_recv(s,buf,sizeof(buf),0) < 0 )
    return -1;
    if ( (p = memchr(buf,'\n',sizeof(buf))) != NULL )
    {
        if ( p > buf && p[-1] == '\r' )
            p--;
        *p = '\0';
    }
    else
        buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = '\0';
    strcpy(str,buf);
    return strlen(str);
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
/*is some thing wrong here?*/
int shutdownCon(socket_t s){
    char buff[1024];
    if (shutdown(s->h,2)== SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wsa_error("shutdownCon",-1);
        return -1;
    }

    while(socket_gets(s,buff)> 1);
    if(closesocket(s->h) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wsa_error("shutdownCon",-1);
        return -1;
    }
    socket_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
/*is some thing wrong here?*/
int init(socket_t *s){
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    struct sockaddr_in *addr_in = (struct sockaddr_in *)&saddr;
    /* socket (TCP/IP) API initialization: */
    if ( socket_setup() < 0 )
    return -1;
    /*
    * Connect to the instrument:
    */
    /* set destination IP address and TCP port: */
    memset(addr_in,0,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    addr_in->sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr_in->sin_port = htons(PORT);
    addr_in->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);
    /* create socket: */
    *s = socket_create();
    if ( !*s )
        return -1;
    #if debug
    fprintf(stderr,"socket_connect() ...\n");
    #endif
    if ( socket_connect(*s,(struct sockaddr *)&saddr,sizeof(saddr)) < 0 )
        return 1;
    #if debug
    fprintf(stderr,"socket_connect(): done\n");
    #endif
    return 1;
}
int recon(socket_t *s){
    shutdownCon(*s);
    init(s);
    return 0;
}

void printTime(){
   struct _timeb timebuffer;
   char *timeline;

   _ftime( &timebuffer );
   timeline = ctime( & ( timebuffer.time ) );

   printf( "The time is %.19s.%hu %s", timeline, timebuffer.millitm, &timeline[20] );
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    socket_t s;

    char buffer[1024];
    char oper[1024];

    init(&s);

    #if debug
    fprintf(stderr,"trying to get id from norma \n");
    if ( socket_puts(s,"*IDN?") < 0 )
        return 1;
    if ( socket_gets(s,buffer) < 0 )
        return 1;
    puts(buffer);
    #endif
    //##################CONF FROM FLUKE#####################
    /* Bring the instrument into a default state: */
    //socket_puts(s,"*RST");
    /* Select three wattmeter configuration: */
    //socket_puts(s,"ROUT:SYST \"3W\"");
    /* SYNC source = voltage phase 1: */
    //socket_puts(s,"SYNC:SOUR VOLT1");
    /* Set voltage range on voltage channel 1 to 300 V: */
    //socket_puts(s,"VOLT1:RANG 300.0");
    /* Set current channel 1 to autorange: */
    //socket_puts(s,"CURR1:RANG:AUTO ON");
    /* Set averaging time to 1 second: */
    //socket_puts(s,"APER 1.0");
    /* Select U, I, P measurement: */
    //socket_puts(s,"FUNC \"VOLT1\",\"CURR1\",\"POW1:ACT\"");
    /* Run continuous measurements: */
    //socket_puts(s,"INIT:CONT ON");
    //######################################################
    socket_puts(s,"SYST:KLOC REM");
    socket_puts(s,"*RST");
    socket_puts(s,"ROUT:SYST \"3w\"");
    socket_puts(s,"APER 0.025");
    socket_puts(s,"INP1:COUP DC");
    socket_puts(s,"FUNC \"VOLT1\",\"CURR1\",\"POW1\",\"POW1:APP\",\"POW1:ACT\",\"PHASE1\"");
    socket_puts(s,"INIT:CONT ON");

    Delay(5.0); /* Wait 2 seconds */
    int opstat = -1;

    while(1){
        //if(opstat != -1)
        //  recon(&s);

        opstat = 0;
        while((opstat & 0x400) == 0){
            if(socket_puts(s,"STAT:OPER:EVEN?")==-1){
                recon(&s);
                continue;
            }
            memset(oper,0,sizeof(oper));
            if(socket_gets(s,oper) == -1){
                recon(&s);
                continue;
            }
            opstat = atoi(oper);
        }

        if(socket_puts(s,"DATA?") == -1){/* Query the measurement */
                recon(&s);
                continue;
        } 
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer)); /* Clear buffer */
        if(socket_gets(s,buffer) == -1){/* read values */
                recon(&s);
                continue;
        }

        puts(buffer); /* Print the value on the screen */
        //Delay(1.0); /* Wait 2 seconds */
        printTime();
    }

    return 0;
}
/****************************************************************************
**/
```

best regards baot

Comment: Why are you trying to do `socket_gets` after you've called `shutdown` on the socket? Of course the `read`, `write` operations are disallowed after `shutdown` is called with a value of `SHUT_WR` (2) in your case. That seems to be the problem. I don't think `closesocket` needs to be called as well after `shutdown`.

Comment: [msdn - shutdown ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx) under remarks you find "1.Call shutdown with how=SD_SEND.
2.Call recv or WSARecv until the function completes with success and indicates zero bytes were received. If SOCKET_ERROR is returned, then the graceful disconnect is not possible.
3.Call closesocket." i should just use sd send, will try that right away.

Comment: it did not work first i got error 10053 and then i got WSAENETUNREACH 10051 and after like 30 trys i got a connection again. @gabhijit thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

The "shutdownCon" function should not return early when one of its calls to a WinSock2 function fails. So for example, if the call to "shutdown" fails, "shutdownCon" reports the error and then exits without calling "closesocket" or "socket_cleanup". So when "shutdownCon" fails it can leave socket and the WinSock2 library in different states (making it difficult for your program to reliably continue, since it doesn't know the state of either).

If I were you, I would also separate the initialization of the WinSock2 library and the initialization of the socket. I would initialize the WinSock2 library once at the beginning of your program and never clean it up. In other words, take the call to "socket_setup" out of "init" and put it in "main" (before the call to "init" of course), and take the call to "socket_cleanup" out of "shutdownCon".

If none of the above helps, you could try inserting a delay between when you close the socket and when you initialize a new socket. If that doesn't help your program probably needs to start checking the error values returned by the WinSock2 library and do different things depending on what the error was.

Answer (score -1):

after creating the socket, certain options can be set.

One of those options is the SO_KEEPALIVE socket option.

Setting the option results in the socket staying open rather than automatically closing.

the keepalive option can be set using something like this:

```
int keepAlive = 1;
result = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE,
               &keepAlive, (socklen_t)sizeof(keepAlive));
```

Comment: No it doesn't. You're confusing TCP keepalive with HTTP keepalive.

Comment: It sort of tries to do that - but not exactly 'keeps it open' The other end can always 'choose to close' so in that sense - you get to know that quickly about it. so `SO_KEEPALIVE` won't help you.